# How can I get the data from input (HTML) to be registered as a button?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, button, input

[Photo of what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r87p4.png)

As you can see I'm trying to register the rooms as buttons after you type it in input. I made those buttons manually but how can I code it in a way that for each room input it makes a button.

I'm using javascript with node.js and socket.io.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up: First, you need to listen for the entering of new chat rooms. Next, you get the value of that field, create a new button (its text being identical to the entered value) and append it to the div containing the other buttons.

```js
function enter() {
  var name = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  if (name) {
  document.getElementById("inp").value = "";
  createRoom(name);
  }
}

function createRoom(name) {
  var newRoom = document.createElement("button");
  newRoom.innerHTML = name;
  document.getElementById("rooms").appendChild(newRoom);
}

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    enter();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text">
<button id="enter" onclick="javascript:enter();">Add</button>
<div id="rooms">
<button>Music</button><button>Family</button><button>Study</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for <3

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rooms = [
  {id: 24, name:"Music", members:4670},
  {id: 17, name:"Family", members:77},
  {id: 10, name:"Study", members:9},
];

const ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});

const roomButton = (room) => ELNew("button", {
  className: "btn",
  textContent: room.name,
  title: `Members: ${room.members}`,
  onclick() { console.log(room.id); },
});

const roomButtons = () => rooms.reduce((DF, room) => 
  (DF.append(roomButton(room)), DF)
, new DocumentFragment());

// Example:
document.querySelector("#roomsButtons").append(roomButtons());
```

```html
<div id="roomsButtons"></div>
```